# Find if speaker is in use?

Tags: android, audio, speaker

In Android , is it possible at any given time to find if speaker is in use and if so which app is using it.

Sorry i did not know how to phrase the question. 
What i want to do is find out if any app (Music Player) is playing a music file either using the loud speaker or the ear phones. Also if possible find which app is using it.

Sorry Don't know how else to phrase this.

Comment: Define speaker and 'in use'.

Comment: @Mgamerz i have made changes to my question, and tried to explain what i need as best i can.

Comment: So you are wondering how to find out if music/sound is playing out of the headphones/speakers/something else (bluetooth) and if it's possible to find out what what app is doing it. That might be hard since more than one can be pushing audio at the same time.

Comment: @Mgamerz Yes that is exactly what i want.So is it possible to this.I am looking through the docs right now, and found out abt Audio Focus but still not sure how to use this to my advantage.

Comment: Sadly I don't know how to help you, never done that before...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed this to find if music is currently playing on the device. I found the function
[isMusicActive()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#isMusicActive%28%29) under AudioManager. It returns true only when music is actually playing,
its false evnen when player is in foreground and paused. Its worked for me so far.