# Detect when sound is playing through earpiece speaker

Tags: android, audio, speaker

### Background

I'm developing an app that monitors the proximity sensor. However, I don't want to monitor the sensor while the user is listening to something through the phone ear speaker. This is because the user will probably have his/her head against the handset to listen, which in turn triggers the proximity sensor, and I'm not trying to detect *head* proximity.

### Question

How can I detect when sound is and isn't playing through the handset ear speaker? Callbacks are preferable, of course, but I'm willing to poll if it's the only way.

Comment: Possible answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14618202/find-if-speaker-is-in-use

Comment: Even if you know if user is playing something nobody says his hear isn't against the speaker. It could be better check if the user is on a call instead. Otherwise you can again reduce causes deactivating detection also when user is playing music with a very low volume and without headphones

Comment: @TheRedFox, checking if the user is on a call is a good solution if possible, but it seems hard to detect if the user is on a non-system call such as a Viber or Skype call. Also, what if the user is listening to music or an audio book through the ear speaker?

Comment: @TheRedFox, I didn't understand your last sentence. Can you rephrase it?

Comment: @Sam yes it is very hard to say what's going on, since you also have a chance that somebody is using the speakerphone but still having his hear against the speaker, :-)

Comment: @TheRedFox, that's right, but that's an acceptable risk for my app. I think detecting when the ear speaker is playing sound is sufficient here.

Comment: @Sam BTW i think the best solution is a combination of things, like detect when there is a call, when user is playing music and so on, of course it doesn't solve your problem of skype or viber.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can approximate this by regularly polling and making the following checks:

- Check if [the audio system](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#getMode()) is not in [normal mode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#MODE_NORMAL).
- Check if the audio is being [routed](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#getRouting(int)) to the earpiece.

I tested this in Android 4.3, and it seemed to work fine with the system phone app, Viber and Skype. However, it doesn't seem to detect music or non-telephony sounds played through the earpiece. I don't think this is much of a problem, because the earpiece generally seems to only be used for telephony anyway.

#### Example

```
public class EarpieceSpeakerState {

    private AudioManager audioManager;

    public EarpieceSpeakerState(AudioManager audioManager) {
        this.audioManager = audioManager;
    }
    
    public boolean usingEarpieceSpeaker() {
        return playingSound()
            && routingToEarpiece();
    }

    private boolean playingSound() {
        return audioManager.getMode() != AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL;
    }
    
    private boolean routingToEarpiece() {
        return !(
            audioManager.isSpeakerphoneOn()
            || audioManager.isBluetoothScoOn()
            || audioManager.isBluetoothA2dpOn()
            || audioManager.isWiredHeadsetOn()
        );
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is the right solution but i think you should at least give it a try, check out [this link](http://developer.android.com/training/managing-audio/audio-focus.html).
Teorically you will not receive focus if somebody else is using the speaker of your phone.

Comment: Looks like it might work, but the only way to receive audio focus changes seems to be requesting focus. However, requesting focus could result in existing playback from another app stopping.

Comment: Actually you could request focus and if you get it just delete the request asap and execute your code.

Comment: Once i have focus, how can i tell if i took it from another app or if it wasn't used?

Comment: If something is using speaker i think you wont get focus

Comment: From reading the documentation, i get the impression that requesting the audio focus takes it away from other apps.

Comment: Mh could be sorry but i didn't try

Answer (score 0):

base solution, you can extend it [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63833034/12761967)

```
 private fun initOnAudioFocusChangeListener() {
val afChangeListener: AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener =
    AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener { focusChange ->
        when (focusChange) {
            AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN -> {
                viewModel.isAppLostAudioFocusLiveData.value = false
            }
            else -> {
                viewModel.isAppLostAudioFocusLiveData.value = true
            }
        }
    }

val audioManager = getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE) as AudioManager
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    audioManager.requestAudioFocus(
        AudioFocusRequest.Builder(AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN)
            .setOnAudioFocusChangeListener(afChangeListener).build()
    )
} else {
    audioManager.requestAudioFocus(
        afChangeListener,
        AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
        AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN
    )
}
```

}